# nextElementSibling freezing firefox

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to search specific text to highlight the link, when it is found. Because the links are not inside the h4 tags I don't know how to solve it.

### html code

```
<h4>Title P</h4>
...
<h4>Title X</h4>
<p class="item">
<a href="url" target="_new">ABC</a>
</p>
<div class="c">
<p class="item">
<a href="url" target="_new">EFG</a>
</p>
<div class="c">
<p class="item">
<a href="" target="_new">MNO</a>
</p>
<div class="c">
<p class="item">
<a href="url" target="_new">XYZ</a>
</p>
<h4>Title Z</h4>
...
```

The text I wanna find repeats under the others h4 tags, but I want to highlight only the ones inside Title X.

### So here is my code:

```
// @grant       GM_addStyle
...
var h4 = document.getElementsByTagName("h4");

for (var i = 0; i < h4.length ; i++) {

    if (h4[i].textContent.indexOf("Title X") != -1) {

        var links = h4[i].nextElementSibling;

        while (links && links.nodeName != "H4") {

            if (links.textContent.indexOf("EFG") != -1){
                links.setAttribute("id","color");
            }
            if (links.textContent.indexOf("MNO") != -1){
                links.setAttribute("id","color");
            }

        }

    }
}

GM_addStyle ( '                                 \
    #color {                                    \
        background-color: #ffd65e;              \
    }                                           \
' );
```

If I remove the while, the browser does not freeze.

### After the answer the working code was:

```
var links = h4[i];
while ( (links = links.nextElementSibling) && (links.nodeName != "H4") ) {

            if (links.textContent.indexOf("EFG") != -1) {
                links.setAttribute("id", "color");
            }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the expected behavior of your code. See the following two lines.

```
var links = h4[i].nextElementSibling;
while (links && links.nodeName != "H4") {
```

You set `links` to the element following the current `h4` element (in this case, the first one, as it never continues), and repeatedly checks if that element is truthy and is not an `h4` element. Nowhere in the body of this `while` statement is `links` re-assigned, so it simple does the same check over and over again, thus causing your hanging script.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this script, but perhaps you intended to do something link this to iterate over the sibling elements?

```
var links = h4[i];
while ( (links = links.nextElementSibling) && (links.nodeName != "H4") ) {
```

Comment: I'd upvote if you didn't have an assignment and 2 order-dependent checks inside a `while()`.  That's "time bomb" coding.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Good point, I added parentheses for clarity and JSHint validation.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to highlight the link with the specific text. With your code it stopped freezing, but I still can't change background color of the text. How would I setAttribute with the new var? links.nextElementSibling.setAttribute didn't work.

Comment: @Comentarist `links` is already set to the `nextElementSibling`, so `links.setAttribute` should work.

Comment: After @BrockAdams tip, it's working now. Thank you both.